# InputPrompt Hidden

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I'm trying to use the [InputPrompt class of the Coding4Fun Windows Phone Toolkit](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=InputPrompt&referringTitle=Documentation). My XAML structure is as follows:

```
PivotItem
-User Control 1
--Subclass of ProgressOverlay
```

In my subclass of ProgressOverlay, I'm trying to create an input prompt then show it when a button is tapped. The problem I have is that when I call `Show` on the prompt, it displays for a second then fades again, making it unusable. Am I missing something?

I'm creating the prompt like this:

```
var ﻿prompt = new InputPrompt() {
    Title = "Add Section"
};
prompt.Completed += addPrompt_Completed;
prompt.Show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved this by simplifying my Views and ViewModel so there are only two nested on screen instead of three.